# c++ ostream output with setw

Tags: c++, string, iomanip

I have an output file name out

using the below code to add a string to the text file:

```
string foo = "Hello, foo";
out << foo;
```

How can I customize a string to input into out file

adding string and numbers with a specific width using setw(7)

```
Your name is:AName  you are 18  
Your name is:foo    you are 30
```

with variable `name` holding the name and variable `age` holding the age

how can I make this code works

```
  out<<  ("Your name is :"+ setw(7)+  name +" you are "  + age);
```

Comment: Note am using a loop to pass by two lists to get the names and ages

Comment: It is unclear to me what you really want to do. Please show your code and describe what it should do and where it fails to do so.

Comment: There can be found examples in the doc. of [`std::setw`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw) which should help.

Comment: Concatenation with `+` is the wrong approach. You should concatenate the output with the operator `<<` instead.

Answer (score 0):

It is just as simple as

```
std::out << "Your name is :" << std::setw(7) << std::left << name << " you are " << age;
```

[`setw`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw) does not return a string that you can concatenate. It returns an unspecified type that can be passed to `operator <<` of an output stream.

Comment: To display names as indicated in the example, we could use `<< std::left`

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
std::string name = "AName";
unsigned int age = 18;
out << "Your name is:" << setw(7) << name << "you are " << age << "\n";
```

If you have a `struct` and database, this might be:

```
struct Name_Age
{
    std::string name;
    unsigned int age;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Name_Age> database;
    Name_Age record;
    record.name = "AName"; record.age = 18;
    database.push_back(record);
    record.name = "foo"; record.age = 30;
    database.push_back(record);

    for (size_t index = 0; index < database.size(); ++index)
    {
        cout << "Your name is:" << setw(7) << database[index].name
             << "you are " << database[index].age << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```